# RecyclerView image slider with full screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

My recyclerview list item has three image and other components.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_view_items"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:minHeight="100dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/car02"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/car01"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/car03"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
```

My each list items has this three images in horizontal.

inside the recycler onBindViewHolder . I have added the lines below

```
 @BindView(R.id.image_view_items)
 LinearLayout imageHolder;

 viewholder.imageHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // open activity of page viewer
                //Log.i("Item", "Clicked");
            }
        });


public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int[] images = {R.drawable.car01, R.drawable.car02, R.drawable.car03};
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public ImagePagerAdapter() {
        super();
    }

....
```

When I click the images on the **list item**, image should popup to full screen and  should be able to slide three images and when I drag the full screen view it should close. (like facebook image full screen slider view on post image)

How can I pass the particular list item images to activity ?
After images loaded. Some how I need to pass the image reference to quickly load ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should call Activity with viewpager. And add transitionAnimation to your imageView.

Comment: did you got what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RecyclerView` Adapter `onBindViewHolder()`;

where you are setting the images for your row, just create a ArrayList and add the three images on that arrayList.It will add the images when setting the images in the every row by position and pass the `arrayList` to your `viewPager`

And set the Listner within `onBindViewHolder():`

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //call Viewpager here
        }
    });
```

**ViewPager Reference** :[View translation in sliding a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251758/view-translation-in-sliding-a-viewpager)

Comment: Keep the three images as it is and create ViewPager by java code on onclick ? Do I need to remove the three images and add viewpager inside linear layout ?

Comment: You need to add only,When you will back and again click on new row automatically it will get the new values of images.

Comment: How to add images in arraylist and differentiate by each row and pass to viewer ? any sample example ?

Comment: https://github.com/MrWangChong/DragPhotoView/ shows add image view inside viewholder and pass to activity.. I think this is clean example.